# How can I pass Tkinter GUI user inputs to other scripts and run them without closing GUI window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am developing a program that parses a file searching specific data requested by a user and returns that requested data as a .csv file. I have the main functionality of the program completed and tested it through manually changing variables which represent potential user inputs. The program is comprised of several scripts forming specific functionality modules.

At this point I am working on development of the GUI with Tkinter in order to obtain the user inputs for use in running the program. All of the user inputs are stored in the `user_input.py` file I have created. The other scripts then import specific items from `user_input.py` for use in the parsing functions. The issue I am running into is I select a file to parse through the GUI and store that file name as a global variable into `user_input.py` but cannot run the other scripts which need that input (the actual parsing of the file) until the GUI window is closed (i.e. `mainloop()` is completed).

I am new to programming and just learning on my own through development of this program. This boils down to two questions.

1. Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of project structure which is causing this issue (i.e, I want to gather user input, run a program that relies on that input, output the results of that program back to the user, have them act on those results to generate final results which are stored as a .csv file)?
2. How do I run a program relying on user inputs while maintaining the GUI on screen without breaking `mainloop()`

I cannot figure out a way to do what I want in the order specified without closing the GUI to allow the rest of the program to run. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well, you kinda do it the other way around, you use GUI to run those functions, so import functions you need, create a new one that will get user input and call the imported function with the input as argument, and assign the newly created function to a button's `command`, then upon clicking the button the function will be called, it will get data from the GUI and then call the imported function with that data as argument

Comment: Best is to use two threads : 1 for the gui, 1 for the other part of the code. Or do it all in only one script.